# Calling Generic Handler .ashx from asp.net code behind

Tags: asp.net, generic-handler

I have a generic handler (.ashx) which is used to download an excel file.
When I try to call it using the code below:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ExcelDownload.ashx?id=123") as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

the file is not downloaded.But,I am able to debug the handler code when the request is made.

But when the handler is used in the anchor tags,I am able to download the file.

```
<a href="ExcelDownload.ashx?id=123">Excel Download</a>
```

Any idea why the first option is not working?

Additional Comments:
In the handler,I am using the below code which works fine with anchor tag.
I am not doing any thing with the response object returned by the request.

```
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.Buffer = true;
byte[] buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", faWorkbookFileName));
context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
context.Response.End();
```

Comment: Did you try doing an absolute URL in the code and see if that works?

Comment: yes,I did but same result.

Comment: what are you doing with the `response` once you get it?

Comment: update your question with this info so it's remotely readable

Comment: You need to refractor the code , move the code written in handler to a class, so that both handler and your new module  can use that, and you don't have to do webrequest to handler.

Comment: added the additional code as requested.

Comment: I want to call the handler on postback.
I want handler to write it to the reponse(download)